# How to use Sphinx3 in an application

Tags: c, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I used Sphinx4 for some time which really fits my needs. I load a recognizer, pass the audio data to it and use the recognized String in my application.

Right now I'm working on a C application (C++ is unfortunately not an option) where I need something similar and thought that I could use Sphinx3 which is written in C.

The problem is that I don't really know how it is used inside an application and there is no "Hello World"-example as Sphinx4 provides it.

I already compiled and installed sphinxbase and sphinx3 and now I can include the sphinx header files in my application.

Now to my questions:

- Is there a "simple" and well documented example application that uses sphinx3 from a C environment?
- How can I load up the sphinx3 engine and call a recognizer with my binary audio data?
- OR: Do I need to start an application like "sphinx3_decode" and call it from my own application? If so, is there an example application for that?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **not** recommended to use Sphinx3. From the website:

> Sphinx-3 is CMU’s large vocabulary speech recognition system. It’s
>   older C based decoder that we continue to maintain. It’s planned to
>   make **it obsolete in** the future, it’s still most accurate decoder for
>   large vocabulary tasks. We are using it as a baseline to check the
>   recognizer accuracy. This decoder is **only intended for researchers** who
>   want to evaluate bleeding edge methods in ASR like tree search method.

If you need to use a decoder you should use pocketsphinx. You can find the tutorial and the API documentation on the website

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/api/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx_8h.html

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't check out pocketsphinx because I thought it's for mobile devices only. I'll look into the examples!

Answer (score -1):

I Recently worked on an Intregated Project on Punjabi Language.
Here are some steps that we used...

- First we recorded the punjabi audio data in a vaccumed room in 16000 hz sample rate.
- Then we took the recorded data and segmented it using Praat Software into small wav and raw files of 2 to 30 sec and saved them in a folder named train.
- Then we took a system having Linux ie. Ubuntu and installed the required plug in like autoconfig, automake etc and untarred Sphinx 3 along with 4 packages that are cmuclmtk, pocketsphinx, sphinxbase, sphinxtrain.
- Then according to the small wav files we made many files like transcription, dic, phone, filler, file id, ccs etc.
- Then we opened the terminal and typed –"sphinx_fe” to check the whether the sphinx is functional or not.
- Then we created an folder named “man” and then in terminal wrote its path.
- Then we run the command- “sphinxtrain –t man setup”. By running this command an folder named “etc” will be formed in “man” folder containing files “feat_paramas” & ”config”.
- Changes were made in the in the config file according to our data.
- Then we moved all the files that we created before ie. transcription, dic in the etc folder in that is located in man folder.
- Then we placed ‘lang1.sh” script in etc folder and remaining 4 scripts in man folder.
- Then we opened the path for etc folder in terminal and run command- “lang1.sh”
- Then we run series of commands in terminal – “mfcgen2.sh” then “verify3.sh” then “hmm4.sh” and at last “end-test.sh” to get the final result.

Rest if you have worked on Sphinx 4 then you may know about the files that are mentioned above in the steps. I hope this helps you.